Socrata: Find all datasets from a domain
I would like to get a list of all data available at the Socrata website for Mesa, AZ using an API from Python. Based on the web search on the site, there are 1176 total results and 305 datasets.
I have tried using the Socrata Open Data Network as described in this answer. However, that only returns 41 results not the 1176 expected:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?domains=data.mesaaz.gov&offset=0
A web search of opendatanetwork gives the same result.
I have also tried using the datasets function in the sodapy Python library. That returns the same 41 results. When I look under the hood of sodapy, it appears to be making an API request specific to Mesa:
https://data.mesaaz.gov/api/catalog/v1?domains=data.mesaaz.gov
In fact, removing the domains filter from the api.us.socrata.com and data.mesaaz.gov queries give the same result, which includes datasets outside Mesa. It appears that the data.mesaaz.gov is misleading and just searches the Open Data Network not data.mesa.gov.
I do not see anything the Socrata API documentation for querying available datasets. There appears to only be tools for query individual datasets.

So mesaaz.gov gets their data from data.mesaaz.gov and citydata.mesaaz.gov
This returns 305 results:
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?only=dataset&domains=data.mesaaz.gov,citydata.mesaaz.gov
Get list of domains (how I got citydata.mesaaz.gov):
https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1/domains

An alternative search that works is: https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?search_context=data.mesaaz.gov.
Some of the same datasets (such as Police Incidents) that appear with domain citydata.mesaaz.gov at https://api.us.socrata.com/api/catalog/v1?only=dataset&domains=data.mesaaz.gov,citydata.mesaaz.gov appear at the expected domain of data.mesaaz.gov using search_context. It's unclear why the difference.

You can go to https://www.opendatanetwork.com/ and search opendata to find most of the domains.

You can also query https://citydata.mesaaz.gov/api/views to get most of the unique IDs available.
